# How to link to a chat room?

Tags: support, comments, chat

Is there a quick way to refer to a chatroom in a comment, like #Java, or we can just copypaste the HTTP url (which is not really verbous in text)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use regular linking, providing a text description with the full URL underlying it:

```
[My link description][1]

[1]: http://mylink.com
```

So, for instance:

[Meta SO Chat rooms](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/) and, to be specific, [the Meta SO 'Opportunity' room](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/387/opportunity)

I personally don't think this takes an age to accomplish, just like linking anywhere else.